# Enter key to send works only once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-events

I have a code that submits the form, whenever we press <kbd>enter</kbd> key on text area... it works, but code runs only once. Whenever I press enter again to submit it doesn't work.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
$('.comment_ta').on("keypress" , function(e){

    if (e.which == 13) {
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }

});
```

and here is the form and text area .. code is in ruby n haml

```
=form_for( ([c,c.confessioncomments.build]), remote: true ) do |f|
        .cmnt
            =f.text_area :content class: "form-control comment_ta"
        =f.submit 'Comment'     , clasS:'btn btn-default cbtn'
```

Now it works well for the first time but whenever I render the new form after submission it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens when the form is submit? Is the `.comment_ta` element destroyed and re-appended?

Comment: re-appended  with same class.. so it should not be a problem i guess

Comment: Yep, that's 100% the problem as you only attach the event handler on load. You need to use a delegated event handler instead

Comment: ya I got the concept of delegation now... thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.comment_ta', function(e){

    if (e.which == 13) {
       $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }

});
```

I assume this is because the `.comment_ta` element gets replaced in the DOM, which means the `.on` event listener will no longer work. By applying the event listener to the `document` instead, the event listener should continue to work.

Comment: No it is localised to `.comment_ta`